# Loop through list of files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in the process of developing a data column check, but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to properly loop through a list of files. I have a folder with a list of csv files. I need to check if each file maintains a certain structure. I'm not worried about checking the structure of each file, I'm more worried about how to properly pull each individual file from the dir, dataframe it, and then move on to the next file. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def files(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    len_files = len(files)
    cnt = 0

    while cnt < len_files:
        print(files)
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
                with open(path + file, 'r') as f:
                    return data_validate(f)


def data_validate(file):
    # Validation check code will eventually go here...

    print(pd.read_csv(file))


def run():
   files("folder/subfolder/")
```

Comment: `return` exits the function, so `files()` only checks the very first file.

Comment: also look into `os.walk()`, it will make this a lot easier.

Comment: @FELASNIPER os.walk() is easier, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right. I took it out and that helped a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of python do you use?

I use Pathlib and python3.6+ to do a lot of file processing with pandas. I find Pathlib easy to use, though you still have to dip back into os for a couple of functions they haven't implemented yet. A plus is that Path objects can be passed into the os functions without modification - so I like the flexibility.

This is a function I used to recursively go through an arbitrary directory structure that I have modified to look more like what you're trying to achieve above, returning a list of DataFrames.

If your directory is always going to be flat, you can simplify this even more.

```
def files(directory):
    top_dir = Path(directory)
    validated_files = list()
    for item in top_dir.iterdir():
        if item.is_file():
            validated_files.append(data_validate(item))
        elif item.is_dir():
            validated_files.append(files(item))
    return validated_files
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you! I'm using python 3.7 at the moment and I've never heard of Pathlib. I'm definitely going to check into this a bit more. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped, let us know if there are any follow-up issues. I'm a recent migrant to 3.7 from 2.7 and there are a few inbuilt libraries like Pathlib that are making my life easier!